# Add servlet filter for multiple paths in embedded Jetty

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, servlet-filters, embedded-jetty

I'm creating a servlet filter which should only handle requests to specific paths in my application.

I can add a filter to my ServletContextHandler easily, for example like this:

```
FilterHolder holder = new FilterHolder(new MyFilter());
holder.setInitParameter("param", "a");
contextHandler.addFilter(holder, "/x", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
```

But how can I add more paths to this filter?
I want it to handle requests to `/y` as well.

I can't seem to find any easy and correct way to do this.
Using a web.xml I would simply define multiple `<url-pattern>` tags under the filter mapping.

Using Jetty version 9.3.0.v20150612.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the filter (via its holder) multiple times.

```java
FilterHolder holder = new FilterHolder(new MyFilter());
holder.setName("my-filter");
holder.setInitParameter("param", "a");
contextHandler.addFilter(holder, "/x", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
contextHandler.addFilter(holder, "*.y", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
contextHandler.addFilter(holder, "/z/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
```

Alternative technique (reusing holder generated from addFilter)

```java
Enum<DispatcherType> dispatchers = EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class);
FilterHolder holder = contextHandler.addFilter(MyFilter.class, "/x", dispatchers);
holder.setInitParameter("param", "a");
contextHandler.addFilter(holder, "*.y", dispatchers);
contextHandler.addFilter(holder, "/z/*", dispatchers);
```

Comment: I tried that, but the init method of the filter was called multiple times which seems wrong.

Comment: Yes, you'll see multiple 'Filter.init()' calls. but its the same 'FilterConfig.getName()' and 'FilterConfig.getServletContext()' in each call.

Comment: Is there any way to do this decently? Because I got about 50 endpoints, which need it, and about 5 who don't... Isn't there a whitelist mechanism instead of a blacklist mechanism?

Comment: @ThomasStubbe that should be a new question in stackoverflow.  And no, this is standard Servlet mechanism.